# WPF: Using a Virtual Keyboard

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have created a virtual keyboard user control to use across multiple windows within my application. I am wondering how I am able to get it to input into a textbox in a window when a key is pressed.

What I am looking for is something like:

```
private void keyboardKey_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
var key = sender as Button;
textbox.Text += key.Content;
}
```

So for example, if I press the key for 'a', then 'a' is added to the textbox.

My mind tends towards some sort of binding property but as I am new to WPF, I have no idea where to begin. Something like

```
<local:QWERTYKeyboard TextboxBinding="TextboxName"/>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is quite complicated task. Fortunately there's couple good tutorials on this subject.

I would recommend you to go through these two tutorials:

- [A Software Virtual Keyboard for Your WPF Apps](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/145579/A-Software-Virtual-Keyboard-for-Your-WPF-Apps)
- [A Touch Screen Keyboard Control in WPF](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32568/A-Touch-Screen-Keyboard-Control-in-WPF)

Especially there first one should contain a sample app which should get you started.

For your particular question regarding getting the text into TextBox. One (naive) implementation is to track the [focus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/focus-overview).

Your virtual keyboard could have property which contains the currently focused TextBox:

```
public TextBox FocusedTextBox {get;set;}
```

And each of your app's textboxes could update the property based on the GotFocus-event:

```
private void txtBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Set virtual keyboards' active textbox
    this.VirtualKeyboard.FocusedTextBox = txtBox;
}
```

Now in your Virtualkeyboard, when one presses "a", you can just update the content of the TextBox:

```
private void UserPressedVirtualKeyboard(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.VirtualKeyboard.FocusedTextBox.Text = this.VirtualKeyboard.FocusedTextBox.Text + pressedChar;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The focus work around does the job and I cannot believe it is something so simple that I overlooked. Many thanks again.