# How to send output from a custom control to a textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, custom-controls

I have created a button layout for a virtual keyboard to be used in a WPF app, and to make it reusable I figured I could give it a `Target` dependency property of type `TextBox` to send the output of the keyboard to. I made a custom control for my keyboard buttons as well, so that they have an `Output` property.

What would be the best way to append a button's output to the target TextBox's current text content? Should I use events or commands, or perhaps something else?

XAML for output window:

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="Project.Views.DataInput.DataInputExample"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Project.Views.DataInput"
             xmlns:cc="clr-namespace:Project.CustomControls"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=Keyboard, Path=Output}" />
        <cc:Keyboard x:Name="Keyboard" Grid.Row="1" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

XAML for `Keyboard`:

```xml
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:Keyboard}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:Keyboard}">
                <Border ...>
                    <Grid x:Name="PART_Keyboard" ...>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            ...
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid x:Name="FirstRow" ...>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                ...
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <local:KeyboardButton Output="q" Click="BtnClick" />
                            ...
                        </Grid>
                        ...
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

CS for `Keyboard`:

```cs
public class Keyboard : Control
{
    public string Output
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(OutputProperty); }
        set { SetValue(OutputProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty OutputProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Output", typeof(string), typeof(Keyboard), new PropertyMetadata(""));

    static Keyboard()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Keyboard), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(Keyboard)));
    }
}
```

CS for `KeyboardButton`:

```cs
public class KeyboardButton : ImageTextButton
{
    public string Output
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(OutputProperty); }
        set { SetValue(OutputProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty OutputProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Output",
            typeof(string),
            typeof(KeyboardButton),
            new PropertyMetadata("")
            );

    static KeyboardButton()
    {
        // DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(KeyboardButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(KeyboardButton)));
    }

    private void BtnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var button = (KeyboardButton)sender;
        var keyboard = (Keyboard)(button.Parent);
        keyboard.Output += button.Output;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure this is the best way but I would also do it this way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48911782/wpf-using-a-virtual-keyboard

Comment: I would definitely use binding, and I would definitely make af property on your costum button control, that during the users use of the virtual keyboard contantly contains the current input from the user.

Then you will be able to setup a binding on for instance the Text dependency property in a TextBox to contain the users input. And by that you will you make a hard coupling of your costum button control to a textbox, but will be able to send the user input to anywhere

Comment: So it turns out I don't necessarily need the `Target` property  as my keyboard only shows up in very specific places, but I will look into making an `Output` dependency property that the textbox text can bind to. But how do you suggest I send a button's output to the keyboard's output?

Comment: Yes, exactly. That is how is should be done - I will make some code sample in an answer ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will surgest, that your virtual keyboard is rather a ContentControl than a button, but that is another thing.

In your costum virtual keyboard control you make a property:

```
public string EnteredText {get; private set; }
```

in your virtual keyboard you make sure this property always contains the current entered text. When you when have a window, there you want to show the entered text in a textbox it can be done in following way:

```
<local:VirtualKeyboard x:Name="MyVirtualKeyboard" />
<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=MyVirtualKeyboard, Path=EnteredText}" />
```

and then by the binding magic the textbox will contain the text the user is entering. And you can use a lot of other type of controls. For instance a TextBlock would be an obivious candidate.

Because KeyboardButtons are placed inside the virtual keyboard control we need a helper method, that also can be handy in many other cases:

```
  public static P FindVisualParent<P>(DependencyObject Dep) where P : DependencyObject
  {
     while (Dep != null)
     {
        if ((Dep is Visual) || (Dep is System.Windows.Media.Media3D.Visual3D))
        {
           if (Dep is P) return (Dep as P);
           Dep = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(Dep);
        }
        else
        {
           Dep = LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent(Dep);
        }
     }
     return (null);
  }
```

Then use this method in the KeyboardButton usercontrol:

```
public override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
   // Base call
   base.OnApplyTemplate();
   // Get the virtual keyboard control
   this.virtualKeyboard = FindVisualParent<VirtualKeyboard>(this);
   // Set the click event
   this.Click += (s,e) => { this.virtualKeyboard.EnteredText += this.Output; };
}
```

And in the KeyboardButton control also have this defined as a member variable:

```
private VirtualKeyboard virtualKeyboard;
```

Comment: Hi Anders, thanks for the answer! Another issue I have is that I've defined the style of a custom control to represent a keyboard key in a resource dictionary and I'm not quite sure how to write the code behind that adds a key's output to the keyboard's output.

Comment: Your virtual keyboard consist probably of a lot of buttons for each key to stroke by a mouse-click. On each buttons click event you add the character the button represent to the commen property EnteredText.For instance:

this.Click += (s,e) => { this.virtualKeyboard.EnteredText += this.Content.ToString(); }

when the character of the button is set as content of the button

Comment: You're right, my keyboard keys do inherit from the `Button` control, but when I try to add a `Click` event to them, I get error MC6024. I have no idea how to add an event handler to the keyboard :/

Comment: When you get MC6024 error, then you have probably set a click in your XAML on the button but without having the event-method defined in the code behind

Comment: I've edited my original question to show the XAML of my `Keyboard` control and the cs of my `KeyboardButton` control, as you can see I have added a `BtnClick` method.

Comment: That is very fine. I miss the code behind for the Keyboard. Because it is here the EnteredText should be defined. And I wonder why you want to collect in a string everytime a user click on a specific button on the keyboard (by having the property Output). It makes sense to me

Comment: I've added the code behind for the Keyboard, as well as the XAML for the view in which I call the Keyboard. What you called `EnteredText` I refer to as `Output`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215513/discussion-between-jansthcirlu-and-anders-hyldahl).

Comment: hi Anders, I've added the `OnApplyTemplate` and the `FindVisualParent` methods to the `KeyboardButton` control but now I get an error that there is no implicit conversion from my custom `Keyboard` control to `DependencyObject`. What could cause this error?

Comment: Never mind, I deleted the `obj` folder and everything resolved! Thanks a lot!